# Too many open files on tomcat server, tomcat 9

Tags: java, linux, файлы, tomcat

Томкат работает с огромным количеством файлов. 
Он открывает файл, берет всё его содержимое и записывает в String следующим образом:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(path), Charset.forName("UTF-8")).reduce("", String::concat)
```

Файлов несколько сотен, а также, возможно, каждый открывается неоднократно.
Увеличение лимитов количества открытых файлов через `ulimit -n`, прописывание в `/etc/security/limits.conf` и прочее мне не подходит: нет необходимости в том, чтобы было открыто огромное количество файлов сразу.

**Вопрос**: как мне "закрывать" файл сразу, как только его содержимое записывается в строку? У меня есть метод, выглядит он так:

```
    String getStringFromFile(String path){

            String answer = "";
            try {
                path = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
                answer = Files.lines(Paths.get(path), Charset.forName("UTF-8")).reduce("", String::concat);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return answer;
    }
```

То есть сам файл меня не волнует вообще, мне нужно лишь его содержимое, которое после открытия записывается в строку - и всё. Как тут же закрывать файл, или как мне добиться того же результата (записи всего содержимого файла в одну строку), при этом, чтобы все файлы не накапливались открытыми?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо закрыть stream, который использует ресурсы ввода/вывода. Stream реализует  AutoCloseable, можно воспользоваться `try-with-resource`:

```
...
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
    answer = stream.reduce("", String::concat);
}
...
```

Или самостоятельно закрывать вызовом `stream.close()`

Comment: От этого зависят очень важные вещи, потому, пожалуй переспрошу, если вы не против: теперь ошибок `Socket accept failed java.io.IOException: Too many open files` не должно быть ?)

Comment: Не должно. Ведь файлы, открытые Files.lines, теперь закрываются вместо того, чтобы быть брошенными открытыми.

Comment: спасибо, а если вдруг опять такая ошибка будет, можно ли что-то ещё предусмотреть?

Comment: Всегда освобождать не нужные ресурсы (закрывать файлы) Если в самом деле нужно такое огромное количество открытых файлов, то надо увеличить предел в операционной системе. Не знаю есть ли ограничения в самой жаве.

Comment: нет необходимости в том, чтобы они были открыты одновременно: программа обратилась к файлу, сохранила его содержимое в строку, файл закрылся, нужно ещё раз обратиться - значит открывать файл заново. Это тем более хорошо, если менять содержимое файла.