# Ресурсобезопасное чтение огромного количества файлов

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat

Есть некий веб-проект, при каждом запросе (а их десятки тысяч в сутки) происходит примерно следующее:

```
скачивается некоторый файл по ссылке в файл 
-> файл считывается 
-> происходит некая программная обработка, сохраняется в другой файл 
-> происходит ещё одна обработка
-> я отправляю запрос, где результативный файл прикрепляется в multipart/form-data
```

Итого три файла: скачанный (через `FileUtils.copyURLToFile`), конвертированный в нужный формат (работаю с аудиофайлами) и обработанный файл (результативный, который отправляю).

Либо же я получаю запрос -> генерирую сам и сохраняю файл -> обрабатываю его и загружаю.

Получается минимум 2 файла, максимум 3. Стала появляться ошибка:

```
Jul 29, 2017 7:38:05 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor run
SEVERE: Socket accept failed
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:682)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Я уже задавал похожий вопрос ([Too many open files on tomcat server, tomcat 9](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660683/too-many-open-files-on-tomcat-server-tomcat-9)), однако там на каждый вопрос была работа только с одним файлом, да и всего-то нужно было считать все файлы в строку, а сейчас, я не знаю, как правильно поступить в данной ситуации. Не сохранять файлы вряд ли получится, и как здесь применить try-with-resources, я не очень понимаю. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Увеличить лимиты тоже не получилось: (https://askubuntu.com/questions/941031/sysctl-etc-security-limits-conf55-invalid-syntax-continuing), я попробовал сделать `ulimit -n 8192`, теперь при `ulimit -n` и отображается `8192`, но я не уверен, что это работает, как надо.

Comment: Руками получается ли воспроизвести проблему с помощью сгенерированных запросов? Если ваш код, который физические файлы открывает заменить на заглушки, то всё ещё получается воспроизвести проблему? Сколько у вас одновременных соединений висят? Запускает ли ваш сервер дочерние процессы?

Comment: @jfs 1. Насчёт генерирования запросов - я, пожалуй, не стану имитировать это, но, я почти уверен, что результат будет тот же. 2. Какие заглушки? Можно подробнее? 3. Как определить количество одновременных соединений? Насколько я знаю, при каждом новом запросе, открывается новое соединение (и поток для него)? В таком случае, возможно, максимум бывает до пары сотен соединений одновременно. 4. Сервер не запускает никаких дочерних процессов, по крайней мере, сам я этого не делаю.

Comment: Про заглушки: просто при запросе  не открывайте системных файлов, а используйте файлы из памяти искусственные (чтобы  fd не потреблять). Если проблема останется, то дело не ваших трёх файлах. Как мониторить соединения? — посмотрите на lsof, ss, sysdig.

Comment: @jsf помимо томката работает ещё mongodb, и в общей сложности соединений запущено больше десятка не было (я теперь понял, о чём вы спросили).Насчёт файлов из памяти - если на каждый запрос создаётся новый поток, каждый раз вызывается doPost/doGet, то как и где мне сохранить файлы в память, чтобы потом каждый раз к ним обращаться?

Comment: @jsf я сохраняю аудиофайл в формате `mp3`, конвертирую его в `wav` с помощью `javazoom jlayer`, обрабатываю с помощью библиотеки `sonic`, затем загружаю и отправляю. Либо я получаю текст, генерирую из него голосовую запись с помощью `amazon polly`, конвертирую опять же, обрабатываю той же библиотекой и опять загружаю. Если бы я мог всё это сделать, не сохраняя ничего в файлы, было бы превосходно, но я не знаю, честно говоря, как это сделать, ибо ту же библиотеку `jlayer` не стану же я переписывать, чтобы она принимала не файл, а поток байт. С другими библиотеками также.

Comment: Цель заглушек определить имеет ли модель в вопросе (что три файла виноваты) отношение к проблеме. Для отладки! Это не решение! Данные любые используйте, но так чтобы минимально на остальную часть кода повлиять. Начать можете вообще с noop (ничего в ответ на запрос не делать и убедиться что проблема ушла)

Comment: @jfs так как сделать, всё таки, чтобы какие-то файлы хранились в памяти, и к ним можно было иметь доступ для каждого потока, которые создаются при каждом запросе к серверу?

Comment: Как угодно. Не имеет значения, это dummy data.